# exclude property of object base on boolean

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that does this

```
function example(senior) {
 return {
  manyotherProps: '123',
  isSenior: senior ? senior : undefined
 }
}
```

but the example function still include isSenior property although it's undefined. I can do multiple return but the object is big I try to avoid duplication.

- update: isSenior is a string value

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure why you need to avoid the undefined property, but I tried this and it works for me:

Option1: Insert if senior is true

```
function exam(senior) {
  var object = {
    manyotherProps: "123"
  };
  if (senior) {
    object.isSenior = senior;
  }
  return object;
}
```

Option2: Delete if senior is false

```
function exam(senior) {
  var object = {
    manyotherProps: "123",
    isSenior: senior
  };
  if (!senior) {
    delete object.isSenior;
  }
  return object;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator to alternate between a `{ isSenior }` object and a `{}` object, and spread the result into the object to be returned:

```js
function example(isSenior) {
 return {
  manyotherProps: '123',
  ...( isSenior ? { isSenior } : {} )
 }
}
console.log(example('foo'));
console.log(example());
```

That said, while that's *possible*, I think the code will be clearer to read if you use `if` later to assign to the property if needed:

```js
function example(isSenior) {
 const obj = {
  manyotherProps: '123'
 };
 if (isSenior) obj.isSenior = isSenior;
 return obj;
}
console.log(example('foo'));
console.log(example());
```

Comment: How about

`if(isSenior) {
      return {
        ...result,
        isSenior
      }
    }

    return result`

Comment: As you can see in the code above, with the `example('foo')`, I'm using a string too - if you want to use the conditional operator, you can use spread to achieve what you're looking for

Comment: Sure, you can do that too, if `result` is already an object - perhaps `return isSenior ? { ...result, isSenior } : result`, though this requires creating *two* objects when you only actually need one

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the object rest/spread syntax

```
function example(senior) {
  const result = {
    manyotherProps: '123'
  };
  return isSenior
    ? {senior, ...result};
    : result;
}
```

Sometimes multiple returns or mutation is actually clearer, but if there are just a few conditions, the above approach is clean and concise

Answer (score 0):

From the performance point of view, it's beneficial that the object returned by your function will always have the same shape (with the properties initialized in the same order). The reason is [modern JIT optimizations](https://draft.li/blog/2016/12/22/javascript-engines-hidden-classes/) such as [hidden classes](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/). It's not just V8 who takes advantage of this, all popular JS JIT engines use similar optimizations.

Undefined/`null` fields as in your example are not just okay. They are preferable. Don't try to avoid duplication. Avoid objects of the same kind having a different shape and/or properties initialization order.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is no direct way to achieve this, one solution would be to delete unwanted properties manually.

```
function example(senior) {
  let res = {
    manyotherProps: '123',
    isSenior: senior ? senior : undefined
  }

  Object.keys(res).forEach(t => res[t] === undefined && delete res[t]);

  return res;
}
```